# Target text without tags using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri, text-parsing

I have some very bare HTML that I'm trying to parse using Nokogiri (on Ruby):

```
<span>Address</span><br />
123 Main Street<br />
Sometown<br />
<span>Telephone</span><br />
<a href="tel:212-555-555">212-555-555</a><br />

    <span>Hours</span><br />
    M-F: 8:00-21:00<br />
       Sat-Sun: 8:00-21:00<br />
<hr />
```

The only tag I have is a surrounding `<div>` for the page content. Each of the things I want is preceded by a `<span>Address</span>` type tag. It can be followed by another `span` or a `hr` at the end.

I'd like to end up with the address ("123 Main Street\nSometown"), phone number ("212-555-555") and opening hours as separate fields.

Is there a way to get the information out using Nokogiri, or would it be easier to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: Split the text above by `(?=<span>)`? Then clean the tags?

Comment: Use Nokogiri. Always, always, _always_ use a parser over regex for HTML/XML, unless you like pain.

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: @A.D. I added some info in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Nokogiri and XPath](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) you could do something like this:

```
def extract_span_data(html)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
  doc.xpath("//span").reduce({}) do |memo, span|
    text = ''
    node = span.next_sibling
    while node && (node.name != 'span')
      text += node.text
      node = node.next_sibling
    end
    memo[span.text] = text.strip
    memo
  end
end

extract_span_data(html_string)
# {
#   "Address"   => "123 Main Street\nSometown",
#   "Telephone" => "212-555-555",
#   "Hours"     => "M-F: 8:00-21:00\n       Sat-Sun: 8:00-21:00"
# }
```

Using a proper parser is easier and more robust than using regular expressions (which is [a well documented bad idea<sup>TM</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I understand it, Nokogiri treats things separated by `<br>` as separate nodes? And the line with just `memo` is adding entries to the hash given in `reduce({})`?

Comment: Yes, in XML/HTML a "node" is either a tag and its contents or a text block.  So `"a<br>b"` would be three nodes, text:"a", element:`<br>`, and text:"b".

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking (rather learning) about xpath:

```
d.xpath("span[2]/preceding-sibling::text()").each {|i| puts i}
# 123 Main Street
# Sometown

d.xpath("a/text()").text
# "212-555-555"

d.xpath("span[3]/following::text()").text.strip
# "M-F: 8:00-21:00       Sat-Sun: 8:00-21:00"
```

The first starts with second span and select text() which is before.
You can try another approach here - start with first span, select text() and end up with predicate which checks for next span.

```
d.xpath("span[1]/following::text()[following-sibling::span]").each {|i| puts i}
# 123 Main Street
# Sometown
```

If the document has more spans, you can start with the right ones:
`span[x]` could be substituted by `span[contains(.,'text-in-span')]`
`span[3]` == `span[contains(.,'Hours')]`

Correct me, if something is really wrong.